# How to download a specific version of Duplicity

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, duplicity

How do I install a specific version of duplicity. The one I have is duplicity 0.6.21 and the one I want is 0.6.18

Answer (score 1):

1. http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=duplicity

   [image]
2. so we want the raring version: http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/duplicity shows:

   [image]
3. The i386 leads to: http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/i386/duplicity/download and the amd486 leads to: http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/amd64/duplicity/download where you will find the actual .DEB file for download.
4. In short:

   - [download i386](http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/duplicity/duplicity_0.6.21-0ubuntu1_i386.deb)
   - [download amd64](http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/duplicity/duplicity_0.6.21-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb)

and after it finishes double click the download and Ubuntu Software Center will do the installation. This does not always work for any download: it is possible that a package depends in something else that is not installed. The 2nd link above ([this one](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/duplicity)) shows what packages it depends on.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I get a error though. it reads 'wrong architecture amd64' this is when I download the i386 from your 4ht point and my pc is i386. I also tried the amd64 download and get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Another method would be using the `=` operand in apt-get/aptitude:

```
sudo apt-get install duplicity=0.6.21-0ubuntu13
```

```
sudo aptitude install duplicity=0.6.21-0ubuntu13
```